# Webpage takes forever to load after login with python selenium-chrome on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, web-scraping, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I'm successfully working on scraping some data from linkedin on my computer using python and selenium. During the process, I'm logging in with a user credentials and then gather some data.

I wanted to run my script every day, so I started transferring the code to AWS lambda. After some painful process, I managed to find some chromedriver/selenium/python configuration that works.

When trying to login with user and password I encountered 2 issues:

1. After logging in I'm getting "Let's do a quick security check" page, but nothing is showing except this text.
2. To overcome the security check, I tried copying a logged-in session cookies from my computer and loading them after the driver gets the linkedin web page. It seems to work, but the loading screen afterward takes forever (I tried even 10 minutes wait and checking using driver.save_screenshot()).

My AWS lambda configuration is:

1. Python 3.7
2. selenium 3.8
3. driver info - platform:Linux, chromedriverVersion: 2.37.544315, version: 65.0.3325.181
4. chromedriver options (I added the last 5 for troubleshooting):

```
options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1024,800")
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
options.add_argument("blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")type here
```

I tried disabling image download and switching AWS regions without success.

I didn't think that transferring a simple code to AWS Lambda will be so hard, please help,
Oron